# DateTime/bool and Null values in .Net

Tags: .net, datetime, nullable

Utilizing .Net I am inheriting from an older class that has DateTime and bool parameters as part of its constructor.  These values are pulled from a SQL database and in the SQL database these values can be null.  When I populate my class and call the base constructor this fails because DateTime and bool cannot have null values in .Net.

I am aware of Nullable types (DateTime? etc.) and I can define my custom classes to utilize them and hold the null values but I have not been able to come up with a way to transfer the null value into a value that the older class with the DateTime could accept.

I hate this idea but, I thought of using a a property to translate the null to a dummy date and then back again but there is no way to determine who is calling the property so I wouldn't know when to feed a null or a dummy date back from the get.

Any Ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't want to shoot an answer for this, but... `DateTime.MinValue` might be what you looking for.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this without modifying that old class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We usually use DateTime.MinValue for this sort of thing if you can't use DateTime? in the older code.

Comment: Agreed; most of the core framework recognises `DateTime.MinValue` as a null-ish date.

Comment: If I have a property in my class that is SomeDate that is nullable when I call this property to push the value in the old class that uses DateTime it needs to push MinValue  If I call the property from my EntityFramework (done automatically behind the scenes I need the Null value.  How would I determine which value to send to each caller?

I am going to have even more of an issue for bool since you really can't substitute a dummmy value and know that it is fake unless I use multiple variables (i.e. Value for temporary value and value stating that the temp value is really a dummy value.

Comment: @Jay - I'm sorry, I don't know of a good way to handle bool since it's essentially a binary value. As you point out, there's no way to know this value is null without introducing some other variable.  My best advice would be to look at modifying the old class if you indeed need this functionality of handling nulls for bool.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this method in combination with null coalescing operator.  It's messy but I'm moving onto other issues :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to use "the current value or a default if missing." As mentioned in another answer, the default date would be a sentinal such as `DateTime.MinValue`.

```
private static readonly DateTime DefaultDate = ...;

...

DateTime? optionalDate = ...;
DateTime date = optionalDate ?? DefaultDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

The older class with a datetime can accept any datetime, so any value would work... (but I would recommend using DateTime.MinValue as others have suggested).

What you might be more (properly) concerned with is how client code that uses instances of the older class will behave when an instance has this "magic" value that represents a null in it.

Is the older clas sealed? If not, Can you create a new derived class with an additional bool DateTimeIsDefined property, and the appropriate code to behave in the appropriate way when the flag is not set (indicating that the DateTime is undefined? if the older clas has it's methods declared as virtual, you could override them in the dervied class with this newer implementation that takes the DateTimeIsDefined property into consideration... and clients that were passed instances of the older class would still execute the older implementation, whereas clients pass instances of the newer class would execute the newer one.

Comment: I don't think the older class is sealed as the OP mentions he is inheriting from it in the first line.